# New data doesnt get loaded on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

Im trying to set a session cookie when someone tries to log in, and the concept is working, but for some reason the new data wont load after just refreshing the page (or using location.refresh() in my case). When a user signs in a session cookie gets added but as i said it doesnt get detected on refresh / reload.
But when i close the tab and open it again it works fine.

Php code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['__sessionID'])) {
    header('location: /login');
} else {
    include 'main.php';
}
?>
```

Js:

```
socket.on('adminSuccess', function(data) {
     setCookie('__sessionID', data.sessionID);
     location.reload();
});
```

Comment: I suggest you to check with a simple console.log that data.sessionID is not empty. If it's ok, give us the code of `setCookie`

Comment: @farvilain I mean theres nothing wrong with the actual cookie or something, as it works if i just reopen the site, but when i just refresh or f5 or as in this case using location.reload, its not really loading the new data.

Comment: save your created cookie in a session and call the session after a refresh

Comment: @StudioMaker Ok I was confused by the JS code and tags, could you remove them, seems to be a pure PHP question. You should also add the relevant code from `main.php`

Comment: I guess @dean is right, take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php